# VBA comparing value of range to other range on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Goal is to color all rows red when the 'Out' column equals the 'In' column, or it differs 0,01 from eachother, while at the same time having the text from 'Name' of 'Out' be equal to the 'name' of 'In'. Picture attached shows a dummy dataset. It is not possible to merge the rows based on an ID, or any other unique combining value.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnwbs.png)

So far I have come up with the following code, which was not used on the dummydata:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim x As Range

For Each r In Range(Range("I2"), Range("I2").End(xlDown))
r = r.Value
    For Each x In Range(Range("H2"), Range("H2").End(xlDown))
         If r.Value = x.Value Then
            If r.Value <> "" Or IsNull(r.Value) Then
                 If r.Offset(0, -3).Value = x.Offset(0, -2).Value Then
                    r.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
                    x.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
                    Exit For
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next x
Next r
```

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: `If r.Value <> "" Or IsNull(r.Value) Then` returns unexpected results, because of `IsNull(r.Value)`. In general, `Null` does not have almost any place in VBA for Excel, unless there is some DB query. To fix it, write `If Trim(r) <> "" Then` and forget about the `IsNull`.

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting?